# How can I see the internal compile commands which fail in a "go get" installation?

Tags: go

I am pulling and installing a package with dependencies, and a compilation fails, in this case not finding a file, `magic.h`.   How do I see what the compilation commands and flags were? The `-v` option does not help. (I do NOT want ideas about where to get magic.h from, this is just an example.)

```bash
$ go get -u github.com/presbrey/magicmime
# github.com/presbrey/magicmime
../../../src/github.com/presbrey/magicmime/magicmime.go:20:11: fatal error:   'magic.h' file not found
#include <magic.h>
```

How can I find, for example, where it was looking for include files, what source *exactly* it was compiling? (In this case the source file I see in `$GO_PATH/src` has that `#include` commented out, and a `/usr/local/include/match.h` exists anyway.)

Comment: It's not commented, it's a cgo's magic comment. It looks for the file where any C compiler would look for it. Make sure you've installed libmagic correctly. See http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled libmagic, using brew, which also installed go.   The question is how to take the lid off what go is doing.  The source file it is using doesn't match the one in the src tree -- so where did it get it from? 
    $ find ~/go/src  -name "*.go" -exec grep magic.h {} \; 
    // #include <magic.h>
    // #include <magic.h>        >-note commented out line

Comment: Have you read the cgo link? It's a magic comment. The Go compiler translates that to a call to C compiler, which in turn fails because it can't find magic.h. Try creating a C file with `#include <magic.h>` in it and compile with a C compiler. It that doesn't fail, it gets interesting.

Comment: Also you might need to call `brew link libmagic` (see https://gist.github.com/eparreno/1845561).

Answer (score 100):

Run go build -x on problem package:

```
go build -x github.com/presbrey/magicmime
```